# Checking to see if ng-hide is or isnt present on a class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a UI element that is an error message that will show this when the error message is not displayed:

```
<section id="errorPanel" class="alert alert-danger alert-top ng-hide" data-ng-show="validationData.serverError">
    Unknown server error occurred. Please try again.
</section>
```

And like this when the error message is displayed:

```
<section id="errorPanel" class="alert alert-danger alert-top" data-ng-show="validationData.serverError" style="">
    Unknown server error occurred. Please try again.
</section>
```

So the class contains `ng-hide` when the message is not displayed.

My page object contains my locators at the top so I have this element located by:

```
private By updateContactDetailsErrorMessage = By.id("errorPanel");
```

Then a boolean return method that was looking to see if this ID is present or not by using `size>0` and then returning `true` or `false`. The problem is that this element always seems to return `true` even when it's hidden. I'm thinking I need to locate this differently. Perhaps look for if `ng-hide` is present or not?

My return method is below:

```
public boolean getUpdateContactDetailsErrorMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    Boolean errorPresent = driver.findElements(updateContactDetailsErrorMessage).size()>0;
    return errorPresent;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element is present in the DOM the `driver` will find it, it doesn't have to be visible. That's why the element is always being located and the list isn't empty.

You can locate the element with `findElement` (single element) and use `getAttribute()` to find out if the element has the `ng-hide` class

```
public boolean getUpdateContactDetailsErrorMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(updateContactDetailsErrorMessage);
    return element.getAttribute("class").contains("ng-hide");
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Always looks so simple when you see the correct way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If the Error Message is displayed, in that case, the height of the element will be greater than 0. Add validation to get the height of the element.
Code :

```
private By updateContactDetailsErrorMessage = By.id("errorPanel");

public boolean getUpdateContactDetailsErrorMessage() throws InterruptedException {
    Boolean errorPresent = driver.findElement(updateContactDetailsErrorMessage).size().height>0;
    return errorPresent;
}
```